# Can we update iOS app metadata (app icon, bundle identifier, app version etc.) outside XCode using external script?

Tags: ios, bash, build-automation

I am having a requirement for which I need to provide my suppliers with their own iOS native apps. I already have a base parent app out in app store and all the supplier apps that I need to provide would be almost identical to the original app along with some customisation like having their own App icons, App Title and to show the data representing the supplier inventory only. So my question is it possible to automate the process for updating iOS app metadata for each of my supplier applications using an external script?  On executing script, it should create iPA files for each of the suppliers with values for bundle identifier, app icon given from the script.

After this process is completed, I am planning to integrate `Fastlane` for automating distribution to app store for each of my supplier apps.

Please guide me in the correct path (maybe a blog link or other suggestions) on how should I proceed if I want to do such a thing (Creating script that would modify iOS app metadata for each supplier apps having their own app icons and bundle identifier)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the approach I used: I created multiple targets for each supplier child app that I wanted to create in my main app; Each target having their own separate app icon, bundle identifier, app version etc. Then after using Fastlane I build, archive and upload each target thereby fulfilling my requirement.